# Unable to add a point cloud to PCL Visualizer in QVTKWidget

Tags: qt, vtk, point-cloud-library

I am trying to add a point cloud to a `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer` . I have followed exactly what is shown in this post:
[How to visualize a sequence of TOF-Sensor data in PCL (with Qt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918650/how-to-visualize-a-sequence-of-tof-sensor-data-in-pcl-with-qt/11939703#11939703)?

However when I try to add a point cloud in the constructor, it fails an assertion somewhere in Boost:

```
external.linux/include/boost/unordered/detail/table.hpp:387: std::size_t boost::unordered::detail::table<Types>::min_buckets_for_size(std::size_t) const [with Types = boost::unordered::detail::map<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, pcl::visualization::CloudActor> >, std::basic_string<char>, boost::hash<std::basic_string<char> >, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> > >, std::size_t = long unsigned int]: Assertion `this->mlf_ != 0' failed.
```

I have no idea, what this about. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have figure out what that problem was. I have VTK and PCL built from source that were compiled with Boost 1.46 (system install). In my project, however everything is linked to Boost 1.48. Thus PCL was compiled with a different boost version than what it was linking with.